# How does white powder coat change aluminum emissivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

I have a telescope with an aluminum tube powder coated white. I took 940 temperature data points from a temp sensor attached to the tube and a weather station for ambient temperature.
It seems the tube cools below the ambient temperature with a maximum of 4 degrees Celsius, during the night.
What could be the mechanism? Does the paint change the emissivity or ..?
I thought the aluminum tube will reach an echilibrium with the ambient but it seems this is not the case.

Comment: The night sky is much colder than the surrounding air (think cosmic microwave background). This is why you can make ice outdoors at night even if the air temperature is above freezing - the water radiates heat to the sky. There should be a difference in the delta between clear and cloudy skies.

Comment: Indeed it was a clear cloudless night. So it seems the tube radiates the energy and it tries to achieve echilibrium with the outer space

Comment: White should reduce the emissivity,and absorption, at least in the visible. Black would increase it. But even so, it will radiate and cool itself.